# alternate execution between two for loop in python

Tags: python

I have two strings that contains values that should be joined together, that means value one in string1 with values two in string2. Here is the code that I have tried it:

```
str1 = "John,Gabriel,Isaac,Albert"
str2 = "Cena,Heins,Newton,Einstein"
for x,y in str1.split(','),str2.split(','):
    print (x+y)
```

I have got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: use `zip(str1.split(','),str2.split(','))`

Comment: Can the strings contain a different number of fields?

Comment: in my case no, but in general yes they can have differnt number of fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `zip`, it returns an iterator (in Python 2 just a list) which spits out tuples with values combined from specified sources:

```
str1 = 'John,Gabriel,Isaac,Albert'
str2 = 'Cena,Heins,Newton,Einstein'

for x, y in zip(str1.split(','), str2.split(',')):
    print(x + y)
```

Answer (score 1):

To address what the actual problem is, this line:

```
for x,y in str1.split(','),str2.split(','):
```

Does not mean what you intend.

There are two things going on.

```
for i in s:
```

Iterates over elements of `s`, assigning them to `i`. `s` in your case is:

```
>>> str1.split(','),str2.split(',')
(['John', 'Gabriel', 'Isaac', 'Albert'], ['Cena', 'Heins', 'Newton', 'Einstein'])
```

That is, a sequence of 2 elements, each being a list. So your loop would iterate twice with `i` being set to one of those lists each time.

On top of that, you're also trying to unpack `i`, effectively, trying to assign `x, y` with one of those lists, the same as this:

```
>>> x, y = ['John', 'Gabriel', 'Isaac', 'Albert']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

This doesn't work because there are more values on the right, than names on the left.

The solution is to construct a new sequence that has pairs of values from each list, and iterate over that instead, as other have said, using `zip`.

Answer (score 1):

In case the number of fields in each string might be different you can use [`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) for Python 3, or [`itertools.izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) in Python 2:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

str1 = "John,Gabriel,Isaac,Albert,Aristotle"
str2 = "Cena,Heins,Newton,Einstein"

for firstname, surname in zip_longest(str1.split(','), str2.split(','), fillvalue=''):
    print('{}{}{}'.format(firstname, ' ' if firstname and surname else '', surname))
```

Output:

```
John Cena
Gabriel Heins
Isaac Newton
Albert Einstein
Aristotle
```

Otherwise, if you know for certain that the names are always paired, you can just use `zip()`.